# Using a variable in a SQLITE Where clause in Node.js

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I am new to SQL and am having a hard time writing an SQL query for my node application. I would like to use a variable in the WHERE statement, but it seems like there is more to it. This is what I have tried...

```
var itemID = 3;

var stmt = db.prepare("UPDATE tableName SET status = 'Out' WHERE id = itemID");
stmt.run();
stmt.finalize();
```

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You have to move the variable out of the string and concatenate it

```
var stmt = db.prepare("UPDATE tableName SET status = 'Out' WHERE id = " + itemID);
```

With ES6 you can use string substitution. Note the backquotes around the string instead of double quotes

```
var stmt = db.prepare(`UPDATE tableName SET status = 'Out' WHERE id =  ${itemID}`);
```

Comment: Brilliant! That was one of the first things I tried, but I clearly messed up the syntax. When I was googling for answers I mistakenly got the impression that there was some complicated trick to it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

You can also do like this,

// Directly in the function arguments.

```
var stmt = db.prepare("tableName SET status = ? WHERE id = ?", "out", $itemID);
```

// As an array.

```
var stmt = db.prepare("tableName SET status = ? WHERE id = ?", [ "out", $itemID ]);
```

// As an object with named parameters.

```
var stmt = db.prepare("UPDATE tableName SET status = $name WHERE id =$id", { $id: $itemID, $name: "out"});
```

Comment: Thanks! This is was exactly what I was looking for.